# umbraco deployment procedure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, umbraco

I am trying to deploy umbraco website. The website runs ok locally, now when I published the website and uploaded via ftp client, there is internal error when I am trying to access the website.
My question is, since I was using SQL CE database locally, will I be still able to use that DB online or I'll have to use sql server database? 
Furthermore, is there any special method to deploy umbraco application?
Thanks for reading, Laziale

Comment: What do the event logs have to say about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u have an windows azure account load it in to azure it works perfectly transfer your file through FTP . Install umbraco from azure as apps which azure is providing it works perfectly . I am also using umbraco on azure

Comment: Thanks for yor reply. What kind of database do you use, and did you modify the connection string? I have the conn string currently pointing to the app_data folder. Thanks

Comment: SQL azure database is what I am using and no need of modifying any connection string it will be configured in the web.config file. SQL azure can store large amount of data like BLOBS and its performance is also very well with less amount of dollars.The best practice is always use connection string in web.config file rather than app_data folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLCE on line, personally I wouldn't recommend it unless it is a very small DB, and the site gets little traffic; SQL Express is also free and a lot more powerful - but to your question, yes, SQLCE should work.

Perhaps let us see your connection string and the specifics of the error you are getting.